# How to distribute enterprise iOS App to specific iPhone device types

Tags: ios, enterprise, iphone-6

How I can restrict an iOS App so that it can install only on specific device type. for example, I do not want my app to install iPhone5, iPhone5S, and iPhone6. I do not want to control it with deployment target settings (iOS version).
And this has to be distributed using Apple Developer Enterprise Program.

Comment: Best practice is to distribute enterprise apps via an MDM (it removes the need for the user to manually trust your enterprise program and makes distributing updated provisioning profiles easier). Depending on your MDM, it may have the ability to target app deployment to specific device families

Comment: @Paulw11 Please suggest MDM.

Comment: There are lots. Some common/popular ones include Mobile Iron, JAMF, Airwatch (now part of VMWare Workspace One), Cisco Meraki and Microsoft InTune

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the installation of the app on specific devices.

But you can create a splash screen as your first view of the app in which you check the device and prevent the start of the app informing the user.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no direct option available to achieve what you requested, because you can select the device type, like iPhone, iPad or Universal while setting up the target,

You can do this in alternate way, on `applicationDidFinishLaunching` You can simply put a check, if the device is other than the one you wants to provide the support then allow the proceed to the application functionalities, otherwise show a screen with some message showing that, **we are not currently providing support on these devices (iPhone5, iPhone5S, and iPhone6)**

And as you are going to distribute the application via enterprise account, so you will not need it to get confirmation from the Apple reviewers.

Hope it helps!